# Can't enter in my wordpress localhost, getting errors because of custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I uploaded custom plugin in my wordpress localhost,
after I activated it I've got an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare true_plugins_activate() (previously declared in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php:7406) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 7465

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php:4333 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(190): esc_url('https://wordpre...') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #3 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4333
```

Then I deleted this plugin, but anyway I can't enter because of this errors.

I tried to rename plugins folder to plugins_old, plugins.deactivate and etc., but nothing.
Also I entered inside phpmyadmin in options and active_plugins and replace everything with this `a:0:{}`, but nothing changed.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Whatever happened here is a reflection of a corrupted WordPress install, not a plugin (even if this was the trigger). People have got these errors when upgrading WordPress or PHP. Did you do anything that could've affected the WordPress or PHP installation?

Comment: I strongly advise that you open your functions.php file in a text editor, search for "true_plugins_activate" and look inside the contents for any PHP files you don't recognise. I don't think that function should even be there once.

Comment: @SUM1 thanks, but "true_plugins_activate" was in that plugin, in my functions.php there is not. I didn't upgrade anything, just installed a custom plugin.

Comment: Okay. But the error is pointing to lines in the WordPress functions.php file, in the folder wp-includes. Are you sure there are no "true_plugins_activate" in wp-includes/functions.php?

Comment: @SUM1 I didn't understand you firstly, sorry, you mean functions.php in wp includes, I thought you mean in my theme, also I didn't know that true_plugins_activate shouldn't be in functions.php) You can write that I should just remove "true_plugins_activate" and I will point you as right answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would, but I do not think it will fix the problem, because your formatting.php is also missing a function, according to the error. Whatever happened to your WordPress installation was serious. I will write an answer saying what I would do in this situation.

Comment: @SUM1 I removed true_plugins_activate(...) and now everything is fine, I haven't any errors.

Comment: Okay, but please be careful, you still have a missing function in wp-includes/formatting.php. I've posted my answer, so you can read it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we discussed the issue somewhat in the question comments (this is the most important note for context)

> Whatever happened here is a reflection of a corrupted WordPress install, not a plugin (even if this was the trigger). People have got these errors when upgrading WordPress or PHP [...] [but] I don't think that [`true_plugins_activate`] function should even be there once.

Someone also had this problem due to installing a plugin called "Monitization", which was malware.

So I'll say what I'd do in this situation.

- I would open the functions.php file (in the folder wp-includes) in a text editor, search for "true_plugins_activate" and look inside the contents for any PHP files I didn't recognise. This would only give me information as to whether something unfamiliar (like malware in the plugin with a different name) was involved, but it's clear you know which plugin caused this.
- Then, I would reinstall the wordpress files that are corrupted. I would find the version of WordPress that I had installed, then I would download the zip file from https://wordpress.org/download/releases/, extract it, then first copy the two files that show in the error, replacing the originals in wp-includes. I would check if this fixes the problem. Even if it does, I would most likely copy over all the other files. (I might move any plugins or themes I had installed to a separate location, so that they don't get overwritten.)

  - If I was feeling very investigative, before copying, I would do a diff check of my entire WordPress installation with the WordPress download to see exactly what files were different and how. There are many programs that can do this.

You said that everything was fine after removing both "true_plugins_activate"s, but I would not come to this conclusion so fast, because there was another error in the log that affected a totally different file, wp-includes/formatting.php. I would definitely reinstall multiple or all WordPress files after this.